# MySQL has stopped accepting connections from other users than root

Tags: mysql, gentoo

I'm running a mysql-server a long with apache and tomcat on a Gentoo box. To administer mysql I'm using phpMyAdmin. A couple of hours ago I received a call -- a user was unable to login to phpmyadmin. I logged on to phpmyadmin with the root user, and reset the password. The user was still not able to login. I then decided to give it a go myself, and even I wasn't able to login.

I tried creating several user accounts, none of them were able to access mysql via jdbc/mysql-client/phpmyadmin. The only user that seems to work is root.

What's even more strange is that websites that connect to mysql with a user other than root are still able to login and retrieve content from the database (it's mainly wordpress and a tomcat webapp). I have made sure it's not just cached, I was able to post SQL queries to the database via these web apps still. *However*, I am unable to login to phpmyadmin/mysql-client with this user and I am also unable to set  up a connection with this user for any new web-applications.

Any help is **immensely** appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after your `GRANT`'s ? If so, is it not simply a host question (which syntax did you use to create the users)?

Further, I seem to recall that in some error-recovery modes only root was able to login, after which a restart of mysql was required, but it would take an explicit recovery mode start, and wouldn't allow your other websiteusers to log in.